# Dynamically Changing all of the Uitableviewcells height to fill the uitableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have been having an issue for quite some time with regards to an ios app I have been building in swift. I have a Uitableview ,with dynamic properties, embedded within my view controller. And what I want to do is size all of the cells to fill the table view. I have tried:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    tableView.reloadData()
    let height = tableView.contentSize.height
    return height
}
```

but this just returned zero for the height of the uitableview.

Help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to call `reloadData()` from this delegate method, since this method is getting called because the data is being reloaded.

In fact, you don't want to use this method at all if all of your cells are going to be the same height. Just set the table view's `rowHeight` property.

Assuming this is happening from a view controller, I'd override `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` to get notified when the table view size changes and set the row height there:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    tableView.rowHeight = tableView.bounds.height
}
```

You may or may not need to add `reloadData()` there to get the table view to update. Try it without it first. Setting the row height may automatically trigger a reload.

Also notice that I don't use `contentSize` to get the height. That's the height of all of the cells, and it's determined by the row height you set. So again, using it gets a little circular.

Comment: That assumes you want all of your cells to be the height of the table view. That wasn't really clear from your question. If instead you want all of the cells to be visible at one time then just divide the height by the number of rows in the table view.